# Is it possible to override Scaffold or MaterialApp?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm a beginner in flutter and all my application will use Direction: TextDirection.rtl,

Can i override Scaffold or MaterialApp to return Direction: TextDirection.rtl,

Or how can I make all screens in app Direction: TextDirection.rtl

Thanks in advance

Show my code:

```
 return Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Center(),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You can't override a `class`. You can override its methods. Coming to your question, yes you can override `MaterialApp` and `Scaffold` classes' methods. However, there are some methods which are **"uncommon"** to be overridden. You can simply check the documentation for these two classes and get an idea.

[MaterialApp Class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html)

[Scaffold Class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html)

Also, when you want to override a class  (like in your question) if you mean to override the **"constructor"** of this class, then it is **not** possible to override a **base class constructor** in Dart.

Comment: Thank you very mush